# global file_get_contents variable outside of function possible?

Tags: php

I have a json api I'm trying to feed to several functions. I'm not entirely sure how to make the `file_get_contents` global so that it can be accessed by multiple functions at once.

Here is my current PHP code:

```
function getVideoTitle($getVideoID) {
    $json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$getVideoID."&key={MY_KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics");
    $json = json_decode($json_output, true);
    $video_title = $json['items'][0]['snippet']['title']; // Video Title
    return $video_title;
}

function getVideoDesc($getVideoID) {
    $json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$getVideoID."&key={MY_KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics");
    $json = json_decode($json_output, true);
    $video_description = $json['items'][0]['snippet']['description']; //Description
    return $video_description;
}

echo getVideoTitle($getVideoID);
echo getVideoDesc($getVideoID);
```

If I remove the two `$json` variables and place them outside of the function I get an error that it couldn't find the variable `$json`.

Also, would making it a global variable make it run faster? Retrieving the API is currently running pretty slowly. Would it be wiser to switch to Javascript..? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `$json` is supposed to be constant, then I believe you're better to create a class, since you need to provide the `$getVideoID` for the ID of the video, and additionally you have the ability to change the video conveniently :)

```
<?php
class MyVideoClass {
    private $json = null;

    public function __construct($videoID) {
        $this->changeVideo($videoID);
    }

    public function changeVideo($videoID) {
        $json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$videoID."&key={MY_KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics");
        $this->json = json_decode($json_output, true);
    }

    function getVideoTitle() {
        $video_title = $this->json['items'][0]['snippet']['title']; // Video Title
        return $video_title;
    }

    function getVideoDesc() {
        $video_description = $this->json['items'][0]['snippet']['description']; //Description
        return $video_description;
    }
}

// somewhere:
$myVideo = new MyVideoClass($yourVideoID);
echo $myVideo->getVideoTitle();
echo $myVideo->getVideoDesc();

// sometime else
$myVideo->changeVideo($anotherVideoID);
echo $myVideo->getVideoTitle();
echo $myVideo->getVideoDesc();
```

Answer (score -1):

here what i have wrote for you

```
<?php
class Video{
private $data;
public function __construct($videoId, $key){
    $json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$videoId."&key=".$key."&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics");
    isset($json_output) ? $this->data = $json_output : $this->data = false;
}
public function getTitle(){
    if($this->data){
        $video_title = $this->data['items'][0]['snippet']['title']; // Video Description
        return $video_title;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
public function getDesc(){
    if($this->data){
        $video_desc = $this->data['items'][0]['snippet']['description']; // Video Title
        return $video_desc;
    }else{
        return false;
     }
  }

public function change($videoId, $key){
    $this->__construct($videoId, $key);
 }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
include('video.php'); // if you going to save the class in separate file
$video = new Video('Video-Id-Here', 'your-key');
echo $video->getTitle().'<br/>';
echo $video->getDesc();
//new video
$video->change('new-video-id', 'new-key');
echo $video->getTitle().'<br/>';
echo $video->getDesc();
```

and you can add more functions to the class